# Android: Json string with spaces gives "Unterminated object at" exception

Tags: android, json

Whenever I have a Json string object with a space in it I get the following error.

Java:

```
String jString = getResources().getString(R.string.event);
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jString);
```

Json:

```
<resources>
    <string name="event">
        {"Array":[{"Name":"One two three"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}
    </string>
</resources>
```

I am get the following message:

```
09-06 22:35:08.214: WARN/System.err(1079): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 21 of {Array:[{Name:One two three},{Name:Two},{Name:Three}]}
```

This doesn't have any issues:

```
<resources>
    <string name="event">
        {"Array":[{"Name":"One"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}
    </string>
</resources>
```

Am I quoting something wrong?

EDIT: Reading through my own post I noticed that the error message doesn't have any quotes around the string object values. So I changed the " to \" in the xml string and it worked fine. Any idea how to have it not remove any quotes?

Comment: remove spaces and check once array name one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading through my own post I noticed that the error message doesn't have any quotes around the string object values. So I changed the " to \" in the xml string and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in a CDATA block. This should prevent any confusion.

```
<resources>
    <string name="event"><![CDATA[
        {"Array":[{"Name":"One two three"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}
    ]]></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Space in the JSON creates this issue . TRY following json
{"Array":[{"Name":"One-two-three"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}

Comment: If the json is served from server and the values contains spaces between them, what should we do?