# How can keep quotes on strings from string resources

Tags: java, android, xml

This is followup of a previous question ([Android: Json string with spaces gives "Unterminated object at" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327069/android-json-string-with-spaces-gives-unterminated-object-at-exception/7327126#comment-8834692))

When I get a string from a resource file it removes the " unless it is escaped (\") is there a way around this?

For example:

Java:

```
String jString = getResources().getString(R.string.event);
```

Json:

```
<resources>
    <string name="event">
        {"Array":[{"Name":"One two three"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}
    </string>
</resources>
```

jString has a value of {Array:[{Name:One two three},{Name:Two},{Name:Three}]} and I want it to have the following value {"Array":[{"Name":"One two three"},{"Name":"Two"},{"Name":"Three"}]}.

Comment: You answered the question yourself: "unless it is escaped (\") is there a way around this?" What's the problem with that?

Comment: The problem is that I get the string from a server that serializes an object and I don't want to write my own serializer. I think it's kind of silly that it removes the quotes from a string and am hoping there is away around it.

Comment: When are you fetching this JSON obect? At (or before) compile? This doesn't really make sense to me at the moment.

Comment: I'm fetching it before compile.

Answer (score 3):

You can place the JSON document in `res/raw/` and then use [openRawResource(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) to get an `InputStream` from which you can read the JSON.

But depending on the data, I'd prefer saving it in a [`<string-array>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) or something like that.

Comment: Is there any way to make [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) bind the raw resource? Writing [10+ lines of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6349913/5922757) just to read a string seems like a little overkill.