# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 14

Tags: java, android, json

The error message I got is:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 14 of {address: yo test}
```

I think that I should escape the string, but in vain after trying all the method on StackOverflow.
Here is my code, thanks a lot for any help:

```
// src/Activity.java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{
        String str = getString(R.string.data);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("iLoveDrinkActivity", e.toString());
        // org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 14 of {address: yo test}
    }
}
```

And...

```
// res/strings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="data">{"address": "yo test"}</string>
</resources>
```

If the "address" is something else like "test" or "yo" or "123", everything works fine.
Thanks again!!

Comment: It looks like you just have an unescaped string.  What happened when you tried to escape it/how did you try to escape it?

Comment: I have tried "java.net.URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");", "TextUtils.htmlEncode(queryStr);", and <![CDATA[str]]>, but got the same result. In fact, I am not sure what should I do to escape the string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only solution I can find ([Android: Json string with spaces gives "Unterminated object at" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327069/android-json-string-with-spaces-gives-unterminated-object-at-exception)) is to replace the quotes in your json with escaped quotes

```
<string name="data">{"address": \"yo test\"}</string>
```

Annoying though.  Wonder if there's a better solution.

EDIT:

After a little more digging it looks like the culprit is the `getString` method which claims to

> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID. It
>   will be stripped of any styled text information.

The stripping of styled text occurs in native code so I cannot see why it throws out the quotes, but looks like it does.

Comment: String.valueOf(getText(R.string.data)) does not work, either. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's because getString calls getText, which in turn eventually calls the native method that strips out the quotes

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to the question, but I got this error when it was trying to parse malformed json. I was missing a comma between two properties. (Using gson)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<string name="data">{"address": \"yo test\"}</string>
```

Otherwise json parser will process the string *{address: yo test}*, that is not a valid json string, while *{address: "yo test"}* is.

Comment: Yes, it works. But what can I do if I cannot change the data in strings.xml? Thanks.

Comment: @Rainbowbreeze how can change this dynamically from code

Comment: in my fcm response "url"=http://fdssafas when i hit send message in my FirebaseMessageService onMessageRecived with Exception: Unterminated object at character 36 of..please help me

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem.

Below is a request with an error.

https://.../getInfo?...&DATA=[{...,KEY="2500000001”}]

Can you notice that?

Special symbol ” were included.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30800257)