# Parsing JSON from url with exception: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 115

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, getjson

I'm parsing this [url](https://itunes.apple.com/br/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/json) and I've got an exception and don't know how to skip it over... I need to get only names of 100 the most popular apps. There is key "im:name" and inside of it key "lebel", but as I see it is invalid JsonArray, so I need to find the way to get names by the key "im:name"... has smb any ideas how can I fix this?

This is my `AsyncTask.class`

```
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String jsonStringUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/br/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/json";
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonStringUrl);
            // get the array of users
//HERE I NEED TO CHANGE SOMETHING
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("feed"); // probably wrong
            // loop through all users
            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString("im:name");//probably wrong
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is the log

```
    09-10 20:04:03.013  18211-18241/com.yuretsrodik.top100apps E/JsonParser.java﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 115 of {"feed":{"author":{"name":{"label":"iTunes Store"}, "uri":{"label":"http://www.apple.com/br/itunes/"}}, "entry":[n{"im:name":{"label":"Messenger"}, "im:image":[n{"label":"http://a474.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/78/1f/f9/781ff9ea-bf94-5309-4c32-4b901279e54a/mzl.rairyzma.53x53-50.png", "attributes":{"height":"53"}}, n{"label":"http://a990.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/78/1f/f9/781ff9ea-bf94-5309-4c32-4b901279e54a/mzl.rairyzma.75x75-65.png", "attributes":{"height":"75"}}, n{"label":"http://a1675.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/78/1f/f9/781ff9ea-bf94-5309-4c32-4b901279e54a/mzl.rairyzma.100x100-75.png", "attributes":{"height":"100"}}], "summary":{"label":"lcance instantaneamente as pessoas na sua vida, gratuitamente. O Messenger Ã© como mensagens de texto, mas vocÃª nÃ£o precisa pagar por cada mensagem (funciona com o seu plano de dados). \n\nNÃ£o Ã© sÃ³ para amigos no Facebook: envie mensagens para as pessoas na sua agenda de contatos e basta inserir um nÃºmero de telefone para adicionar um novo contato.\n\nBate-papos em grupo: crie grupos para as pessoas a quem vocÃª mais envia mensagens. DÃª um nome a eles, defina fotos para o grupo e os mantenha em um sÃ³ lugar.\n\nFotos e vÃ­deos: grave vÃ­deos e tire selfies ou outras fotos diretamente do aplicativo e envie-os com um toque.\n\nLigaÃ§Ãµes gratuitas: fale por quanto tempo quiser, mesmo com pessoas em outros paÃ­ses. (LigaÃ§Ãµes sÃ£o gratuitas somente atravÃ©s do Wi-Fi. Do contrÃ¡rio, cobranÃ§as de dados padrÃ£o sÃ£o aplicÃ¡veis).\n\nMais formas de enviar mensagens: \nDÃª vida Ã s suas conversas com as figurinhas. \nVeja uma prÃ©via das suas fotos e vÃ­deos no rolo da cÃ¢mera sem sair da conversa, e escolha as melhores para enviar.\nGrave mensagens de voz quando tiver mais para dizer\n\nRecursos adicionais:\nSaiba quando as pessoas viram suas mensagens.\nEncaminhe mensagens ou fotos para as pessoas que nÃ£o estavam na conversa.\nProcure pessoas e grupos para entrar em contato com eles rapidamente.\nAtive a localizaÃ§Ã£o para que as pessoas saibam que vocÃª estÃ¡ nas imediaÃ§Ãµes.\nVeja quem estÃ¡ disponÃ­vel no Messenger e quem estÃ¡ on-line no Facebook. \nDesative as notificaÃ§Ãµes quando vocÃª estiver trabalhando, dormindo ou se precisar dar um tempo.\nFique conectado para nunca perder uma mensagem."}, "im:price":{"label":"GrÃ¡tis", "attributes":{"amount":"0.00000", "currency":"USD"}}, "im:contentType":{"attributes":{"term":"Application", "label":"Aplicativo"}}, "rights":{"label":"Â© Facebook, Inc."}, "title":{"label":"Messenger - Facebook, Inc."}, "link":{"attributes":{"rel":"alternate", "type":"text/html", "href":"https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/messenger/id454638411?mt=8&uo=2"}}, "id":{"label":"https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/messenger/id454638411?mt=8&uo=2", "attributes":{"im:id":"454638411", "im:bundleId":"com.facebook.Messenger"}}, "im:artist":{"label":"Facebook, Inc.", "attributes":{"href":"https://itunes.apple.com/br/artist/facebook-inc./id284882218?mt=8&uo=2"}}, "category":{"attributes":{"im:id":"6005", "term":"Social Networking", "scheme":"https://itunes.apple.com/br/genre/ios-redes-sociais/id6005?mt=8&uo=2", "label":"Redes sociais"}}, "im:releaseDate":{"label":"2011-10-19T15:39:30-07:00", "attributes":{"label":"19/10/2011"}}}, n{"im:name":{"label":"WhatsApp Messenger"}, "im:image":[n{"label":"http://a1554.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/1f/94/ff/1f94ffd9-159e-a247-2c0f-059f86b6c6c9/mzl.ivmblqpq.53x53-50.png", "attributes":{"height":"53"}}, n{"label":"http://a422.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/1f/94/ff/1f94ffd9-159e-a247-2c0f-059f86b6c6c9/mzl.ivmblqpq.75x75-65.png", "attributes":{"height":"75"}}, n{"label":"http://a1251.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/1f/94/ff/1f94ffd9-159e-a247-2c0f-059f86b6c6c9/mzl.ivmblqpq.100x100-75.png", "attributes":{"height":"100"}}], "summary":{"label":"O WhatsApp Messenger Ã© um mensageiro para smartphone
09-10 20:04:03.013  18211-18241/com.yuretsrodik.top100apps W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42044e48)
09-10 20:04:03.023  18211-18241/com.yuretsrodik.top100apps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.yuretsrodik.top100apps, PID: 18211
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.yuretsrodik.top100apps.AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(AsyncTaskParseJson.java:32)
            at com.yuretsrodik.top100apps.AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(AsyncTaskParseJson.java:10)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Will be very very thanksful for the help!! Cuz I'm really stack(

Comment: Seems like a JSON formating error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334385/json-exception-org-json-jsonexception-unterminated-array
im not sure tho sorry

Comment: @TehCoder , yes, it is kinda like that, but I have to solve it. I can't make this JsonArray correct, because this is url... I need to skip it over and search there only for "im:name"...

Comment: @meda, I haven't it, unfortunately, and this is a small app, so no needs...

Comment: @meda, I gonna try it, I just thought must be much easier way... like "search in json's keys" or something...

Comment: oh wait, does `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonStringUrl);`  throw the error ?

Comment: @meda, no, next line `dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("feed");`
I've tried to change this key, but nothing works, because the exception comes before it found anything...

Comment: @Yurets see my answer below, you can ignore my last comments I thought it was when downloading...

Comment: The part that read the data is incorrect. you are replacing a `\n` by a `n` character, rendering it unreadable, making the poorly written parser return null, making you crash at the next line.

Comment: as a side note, your jsonparser class is also apparently reading the data in iso-8859-1 when it is clearly utf-8 (json is specified to be always in unicode, usually in utf-8). The `JsonParser` class that you use is very poorly written (I have seen it in other places), and you should stay well away from it.

Comment: I would recommend you replace `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonStringUrl);` with `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(jsonStringUrl)).getEntity()));` and stop using that `JsonParser` entirely

Comment: But it will not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) for the advice to avoid using `JSONParser`, so I've made all I needed in very shorter time and with less efforts. 
I needed to get root `JSONObject` - [names of applications in `iTunes`](https://itunes.apple.com/br/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/json).
and insert it into database.
This is the full code of the method `doInBackground` in `AsyncTask.class`

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(LOG, "AsyncTask. Do in background");
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        try {//Making a request to server getting entities
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(
                    new DefaultHttpClient().execute(
                            new HttpGet(url)).getEntity()));
            //getting json root object
            JSONObject feedObject = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            //getting needed array in root json object
            JSONArray entryArray = feedObject.getJSONArray("entry");

            //moving though the array
            for(int i = 0; i < entryArray.length(); i++){
                //getting all objects in array
                JSONObject entryObjects = entryArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //taking objects with needed key
                JSONObject nameObject = entryObjects.getJSONObject("im:name");
                //getting string name
                String name = nameObject.getString("label");
                //putting data into ContentValues - name and id (for making a numbers
                // next to records in ListView)
                cv.put(DB.COL_NAME, name);
                cv.put(DB.COL_ID, i+1);
                mDB.insert(cv);
                //just controlling in log
                Log.d(LOG, "" + name);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the values the right way, check this:

```
JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonStringUrl);
JSONObject feeds = json.getJSONObject("feed");

dataJsonArr = feeds.getJSONArray("entry");
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = c.getString("im:name");
    Log.d("mylog", "name = " + name);
}
```

You probably want to append this data into an array list, otherwise you would be overwriting these variables.

Please **note**  org.json is a limited library i have personally experienced its limitation when the json data is too large.

I suggest you to ditch it and use GSON or jackson which are fare more advanced.

Comment: Impossible, which line

Comment: irrelevant to the question

Comment: @njzk2 and so is your comment irelevant to my answer

Comment: @Yurets if you cannot log the full json it means you need to switch the library

Comment: @meda, it seems like yeah... thank you for your efforts! I appreciate your time, honestly!

Answer (score 0):

First You make a call get the result into a string called json.
Then You have to convert the string into Json object

```
          String json = null;  
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;  JSONObject feedsObject = null;


     json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(jsonStringUrl);
       if (json != null) {
    try {
         jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        feedObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("feed");
```

For a better understanding visit http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/ and paste your json data there.
On the right you have a settings button---> show types
You can find what are objects, strings and arrays

See the image below. You were trying get a an object not an array

[image]

Comment: unrelated to the question

Comment: njzk2 He is trying to get an object called feeds. But In his code, He wrote.........    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("feed"); // probably wrong ........... It should be corrected or not?

Comment: the error is related to the fact that `JsonParser` returns null because the part that reads the data from the network is broken

Comment: @njzk2, yes, you got that correctly! I've checked this json is invalid.. do you know the way how I just can get those names in the most easier way according to code I've already wrote? and I changed encoding already, thanks!

Comment: @Yurets: see my comments under the question. The networking part is the issue. I have posted in comment a much shorter way of obtaining the json object.