# I need to receive data from server in JSON format in my Android app

Tags: android, json

Here is my JSON

```
 {
  "keys": [
    "10_Ultimate",
    "20_Yemensoft"
  ]
}
```

When I hit directly in the Url I am getting correct response but not from Android. Also I have seen in jsonlint the JSON format is correct. But I am getting following message:

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 11 of
>   [B@41c16df8

Comment: say the url that get json from it.

Comment: client.get("http://192.168.1.15:8080/AndroidRest/financial/finList", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                  JSONObject jsnObj  = new JSONObject();
                  String res = response.toString();

Comment: 'http://192.168.1.15:8080/AndroidRest/financial/finList' this url is on your localhost of pc. you cant access this on your phone! select an url on internet!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771184/parsing-json-from-url-with-exception-error-parsing-data-org-json-jsonexception

Comment: gettinr error at JsonObject jso = new JsonObject(res);

Answer (score 0):

when i hit the Url
http://192.168.0.103:8080/AndroidRest/financial/finList

I am getting correct json response Also i validated in jsonlint.com

```
{
  "keys" : [ "10_Ultimate", "20_Yemensoft" ]
}
```

when i try to deserialize from android it saysorg.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 11

```
 @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                  JSONObject jsnObj  = new JSONObject();
                  String res = response.toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);
                    JSONArray jsnArry = json.getJSONArray("keys");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < jsnArry.length() ; i++){
                         jsnObj = jsnArry.getJSONObject(i);
                    }
                    Log.d("jsnObj",jsnObj.toString());
                    Log.d("jsnArry",jsnArry.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("The Positive  are",res);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I have tested):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"keys\" : [ \"10_Ultimate\", \"20_Yemensoft\" ]\n" +
                "}";

        JSONObject jsnObj  = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsnArry = json.getJSONArray("keys");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsnArry.length() ; i++){
                jsnObj.put(String.valueOf(i), jsnArry.getString(i));
            }
            Log.d("jsnObj", jsnObj.toString());
            Log.d("jsnArry",jsnArry.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("The Positive  are", jsonString);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mr  Pham. You are right but i want to retreive resposne from server

Comment: I know. I mean that you try replace `jsnObj = jsnArry.getJSONObject(i);` by `jsnObj.put(String.valueOf(i), jsnArry.getString(i));`

Comment: exception pccurs in JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr)

Comment: Also I am getting difference in response in Advanced Rest Client and Rest Client